# JWPlayer aspect ratio keeps 4:3 for my 16:9 video

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, jwplayer

I am loading an RTMP video stream in JWPlayer. The video stream should be 16:9 but is displayed as 4:3.

My embed code:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("target");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "rtmp://mystreamhere",
    autostart: true,
    repeat: "always",
    primary: "flash",
    controlbar: "none",
    icons: false,
    width: "100%",
    aspectratio: "16:9"
});
```

I am also reading the metadata of the video to see if there is something weird going on. It only includes the width of the video, is that correct? Shouldn't it include height or aspect ratio?

My stream metadata:

```
bandwidth: "1.79769313486231e+308"
bufferfill: 0
qualitylevel: 0
screenwidth: 820
transitioning: "false"
```

Can I somehow force JWplayer to display the video as 16:9 ? Or is there something missing in my code?

Comment: In JW Player 6, the correct value for repeat is true or false, not "always." Ditto for controlbar - true or false. There is no such thing as an "icons" attribute. But otherwise, your JW embed code looks OK, and should work. Can't help with the stream - not my "thing."

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under:

```
file: "rtmp://mystreamhere",
```

Try to add:

```
stretching: "exactfit",
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped, although I can't be 100% sure - this is because the provider has now updated his metadata to include both the width and the height.

Comment: No problem! Ah, okay, that is good that they are doing that now.